# glGenBuffers and glGenTextures always return 0

Tags: c#, opengl

### Setup

I'm using `System.Windows.Forms.Form` as window source. *Constructor:*

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

---

*Form-Load:*

```
_Device = new Device(this, DeviceConfiguration.SelectConfiguration(Bits.Eight, Bits.Eight, Bits.Eight, Bits.Eight, Bits.Twentyfour, Bits.Eight, true, true), 1024, 768);
Debug.WriteLine(GL.GetString(GL.GL_EXTENSIONS));

base.OnLoad(e);
```

In the load method the device configuration is selected, which is actually working. Calls like `GL.GetString(GL.GL_EXTENSIONS)` are working. All gl-methods are loaded too so all used methods are supported.

---

*Form-Shown:*

```
Application.Initialize(this);
RenderSettings = new RenderSettings(this);

Debug.WriteLine("After setup render settings: " + GL.GetErrorDescription());

_Textures[0] = Resources.LoadTexture("Resources\\Buttons\\btn_big_bg_normal.dds");
_Textures[1] = Resources.LoadTexture("Resources\\Buttons\\btn_big_bg_normal.dds");


base.OnShown(e);

_IsShown = true;
```

The `Application.Initialize(this)` initializes the framework used ( written by me ) and is also initializing a default shader, which is working, and model which is not working.
This causes the rendering later to fail because the returning handle is invalid.

### Framework

I've a own OpenGL-wrapper which has enums for all parameters to enable development without looking in the OpenGL-references many times. As example the method `glGenBuffers`:

```
[MethodGL]
public delegate void glGenBuffers(Int32 count, ArrayBufferHandle[] buffers);
```

The `ArrayBufferHandle` definition:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a handle to a buffer
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 4)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public struct ArrayBufferHandle
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    UInt32 Handle;
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the buffer is valid
    /// </summary>
    public Boolean IsValid { get { return Handle > 0; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the default array buffer
    /// <br>which is used to reset bindings</br>
    /// </summary>
    public static ArrayBufferHandle Default { get { return new ArrayBufferHandle(); } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the string representation of the current object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The current object represented as string</returns>
    public override String ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("[ArrayBufferHandle Handle:{0} Valid:{1}]", Handle, IsValid);
    }
}
```

Of course the shader creation is working and uses the types like the shown above.

### Conclusion

I don't think i've much more to say to the issues i've faced. `glGenBuffers` and `glGenTextures` returning zero and i don't know why. The setup seems like others i've already used.

Of course the window is shown with a blue background when not rendering any models and i don't have any errors when using `glGetError`.

Comment: have you tried running your program through gDebugger with gl warnings set to full? (and break on errors enabled)

Comment: @Necrolis Nope, not yet, i didn't know that the tool exists. I going to try it now. Thank you.

Comment: I am reading your post for the third time, but still do not understand your problem...

Comment: @PaulMichalik That glGenBuffers and glGenTextures always returning 0.

Comment: Are the actual gl functions failing or are your wrappers not working as expected?

Comment: @PaulMichalik `glGenBuffers` is the same as always. They do not have been changed except i changed the array parameter to a type which matches a uint. And also, as explained in the text, the shaders are working.

Comment: @Necrolis gDebugger is not working with C#/.NET and i don't have a pc which has a amd device which would support the newer version.

Comment: Could you try adding [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0)] before ArrayBufferHandle[] buffers argument? I'm pretty sure something is wrong with your marshalling code..

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko The size is already given to the the method as first argument and http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenBuffers.xml shows that the argument is a pointer type, not array.

Comment: But you are passing array, not pointer. If you want pointer, then use "out ArrayBufferHandle biuffers) - only disadvantage will be that you'll be able to generate only one buffer at a time. If you want to keep array in C#, then try MarshalAs to instruct it marshal it correctly (not sure exactly) if it will help).

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko You are correct, there have been a marshaling issue. But it's only causes by the structure in the array and not by passing of the array itself, which is working when you add another method to it with the signature: `void glGenBuffer(Int32 count, UInt32[] buffers);`. As solution i added the `[Out]` attribute to the struct-array. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Thanks to **Mārtiņš Možeiko** who led me into the right direction.

As it turns out the method `void glGenBuffer(Int32 count, UInt32[] buffers)` is working, but the method `void glGenBuffers(Int32 count, ArrayBufferHandle[] buffers)` isn't. Both have a 4-byte / element array which is passed but .NET seems to handle them different. The solution has been simple:

```
void glGenBuffers(Int32 count, [Out]ArrayBufferHandle[] buffers)
```

Add a `Out` attribute to the array.